# iOS SDK Core Graphics game object rotation?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, rotation

How can I rotate objects like a rectangle or circle in core graphics? and is it possible to do this with Core Animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the transform property of the view (which is animatable) or use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to make a transform you can apply to your context when drawing.

Comment: for this you need to include quartzcore framework into your project

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Double {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / CGFloat(180.0)
    }
}
class Rectangle: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect.insetBy(dx: 90, dy: 100))
        context?.translateBy(x: rect.midX, y: -100)
        context?.rotate(by: 45.0.degreesToRadians)
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        context?.setLineWidth(5.0)
        context?.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}
```

[image: The rectangle is rotated by 45 degrees.]

**Add Animation**

```
class Rectangle: UIView {
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect.insetBy(dx: 90, dy: 100))

            // Add shape layer
            let rectangle = CAShapeLayer()
            rectangle.frame = bounds
            rectangle.path = path.cgPath
            rectangle.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(rectangle)

            // create transform
            let transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(90.0.degreesToRadians, 0, 0, 1)

            // Animate the transform
            let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
            anim.fromValue = CATransform3DIdentity
            anim.toValue = transform
            anim.duration = 2.0
            anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
            layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
        }
    }
```